# Kotlin IntelliJ IDEA update - Top-Level function 'main()' not found in package

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I have a project, only one among others, that always loses its 'main()' after updates.

The Run config says: "Warning: Class 'MainKt' has no 'main()' method, even the Main.kt file contains a fun main() {}.
Note the 'main' is not highlighted like in a healthy project.

I tried to remove the Main.kt and create an other one. Same issue.

I tried to check .idea/* files and compare with healthy projects. Didn't found something different. But maybe I hadn't not well seen.

I had to recreate my project from crash 3 times.

Any idea? (pun not intended)

Comment: Is `Main.kt` a Kotlin source file or an `object`?

Comment: A regular source file

Comment: Create an `object` such as `object Main`  and add the main method as follows
`@JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) { }
`

Comment: Marvelous. It works. I had try to recreate the Class Main with a companion object block with a main() but it didn't work.

Comment: Glad it worked. I am surprised it didn't work in a `companion object`, did you forget `@JvmStatic` annotation? Kotlin doesn't enforce everything inside classes approach like in Java, but you should have static context in order to put `main`.

Comment: What version of Kotlin are you using? Does it still work from the command line through Gradle?

Comment: I just made some additional tries. The only thing to do is to go back to the main func signature before 1.04, like you wrote it: main(args: Array<String>) rather than main(). I tried without creating an object Main or a class Main. It simply works. Could be a kotlin level / version that was changed at update?

Comment: Kotlin 1.4.10. Not a project with Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to change the minimal...

```
fun main() {...}
```

by:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) { }
```

From there, the main(...) function backed to be visible for IntelliJ